# integral from 1 to infinity of $\frac{5}{(4x+2)^3}$

Tags: improper-integrals

I have solved the integral:

$$\int_1^\infty{\frac{5}{(4x+2)^3}}dx$$

using u substitution and I am not getting the correct answer. I am missing some step here or making an algebra error. I am not sure what is wrong. The work yields a finite answer (I am doing the problem for a integral test on a series), just the wrong one. Could someone work through the steps?

I first moved 5 out as a constant. I then supposed u=4x+2 and got 1/4du=dx. That left me with the integral of 1/4(u^3)du from 6 to infinity (changing the bounds to u by plugging the original bounds into u=4x+2) I moved 1/4 out as a constant, leaving me with 5/4 as a constant. I integrated to 5/4(-1/4(u^4) evaluated from 6 to infinity). I solve that and get -5/20736.

Comment: It would be good if you showed your calculation, so that one could point out the error (if any).

Comment: Please show us what you've done.

Comment: Show us the answer you did get, and how you got it. What substitution did you use?, e.g. That way we can zero in on your error, if there is one.

Comment: Great minds think alike, I see....

Comment: My guess is that you did not change the lower limit of integration from 1 to 4 or left out a factor of 4 when changing dx.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple case of confusion over how to integrate a positive power in the denominator.  The antiderivative of $1/u^3$ is $-1/(2u^2)$, not $-1/(4u^4)$.  I.e.,

$$\int {du\over u^3}={-1\over2u^2}+C$$

or

$$\left(1\over u^2\right)'=(u^{-2})'=-2u^{-3}$$

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem $$\int_1^\infty{\frac{5}{(4x+2)^3}}\mathrm dx,$$
first substitute for $u = 4x+2$ and $\mathrm du = 4 \space \mathrm dx$. This gives $$\frac{5}{4}\int_1^\infty{\frac{1}{u^3}\mathrm du}.$$
Since $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm du}\left[-\frac{1}{2u^2}\right] = \frac{1}{u^3},$$
the integral will evaluate to $$\frac{5}{4}\left[-\frac{1}{2u^2}\right]^{\infty}_{x=1},$$
and substitute for $x$ to get
$$\frac{5}{4}\left[-\frac{1}{2(4x+2)^2}\right]^{\infty}_1 = \frac{5}{4}\left(\frac{1}{72}\right) = \frac{5}{288}.$$
QED

Answer (score 0):

we suppose that u=4x+2
du=4dx , therefore dx=1/4 (du)

Answer (score 0):

I first moved 5 out as a constant. I then supposed u=4x+2 and got 1/4du=dx. That left me with the integral of 1/4(u^3)du from 6 to infinity (changing the bounds to u by plugging the origional bounds into u=4x+2) I moved 1/4 out as a constant, leaving me with 5/4 as a constant. I integrated to 5/4(-1/4(u^4) evaluated from 6 to infinity). I solve that and get -5/20736.

Comment: May want to delete this answer now that you've move it to the body of your question. Unless you feel it adequately answers your question :)

Comment: embarrassed to ask, but I can't figure out how. There is not an option in the "edit" menu. Where do I delete it?